# GA Event Tracking + onClick="document.location.href='

Tags: button, onclick, event-tracking

The developer who made a site we're working on has buttons linking to PDF downloads using:

```
<button onClick="document.location.href='doc.pdf'"> Doc Name </button>
```

However, we also need to track events for these (we don't want to inflate pageviews with PDF downloads), using:

```
<button onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PDFs', 'Download', 'Doc Name']);""> Doc Name </button>
```

So, the issue is, how can I do GA event tracking without having the two requisite 'onClick's conflicting?

I was thinking about triggering the GA Event with 'onMouseDown,' but this would be less accurate, no?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use multiple Javascript statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="download-pdf" onclick="document.location.href='doc.pdf';_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PDFs', 'Download', 'Doc Name']);"> Doc Name </button>
```